# parse json object to json array using php.

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am having people rsvp for a wedding. I want it so people can submit their rsvp data and have that data go into a json array. I then want to take that array and put it into a table.

I have this array right here:

```
{
    "weddingRSVP": [
        {
            "success": true,
            "FirstName": "k",
            "LastName": "k",
            "Email": "k",
            "Phone": "k",
            "Comments": "kk",
            "GuestNumber": "0",
            "Guest1": "k",
            "Guest2": "k",
            "Guest3": "k"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I got when I ran my code:

```
{
    "0": {
        "success": true,
        "FirstName": "l",
        "LastName": "l",
        "Email": "l",
        "Phone": "l",
        "Comments": "l",
        "GuestNumber": "0",
        "Guest1": "l",
        "Guest2": "l",
        "Guest3": "l"
    },
    "weddingRSVP": [
        {
            "success": true,
            "FirstName": "k",
            "LastName": "k",
            "Email": "k",
            "Phone": "k",
            "Comments": "kk",
            "GuestNumber": "0",
            "Guest1": "k",
            "Guest2": "k",
            "Guest3": "k"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is what i want:

```
{
    "weddingRSVP": [
        {
            "success": true,
            "FirstName": "k",
            "LastName": "k",
            "Email": "k",
            "Phone": "k",
            "Comments": "kk",
            "GuestNumber": "0",
            "Guest1": "k",
            "Guest2": "k",
            "Guest3": "k"
        },
        {
            "success": true,
            "FirstName": "l",
            "LastName": "l",
            "Email": "l",
            "Phone": "l",
            "Comments": "l",
            "GuestNumber": "0",
            "Guest1": "l",
            "Guest2": "l",
            "Guest3": "l"
        }
    ]
}
```

and this is all my php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/javascript');

$fname =$lname= $email = $tel = $comment = $guest = $guestnum =$guest1=$guest2=$guest3= "";

$json = array(

    'success' => false,
    'FirstName' => 0,
    'LastName' => 0,
    'Email' => 0,
    'Phone' => 0,
    'Comments' => 0,
    'GuestNumber' => 0,
    'Guest1' => 0,
    'Guest2' => 0,
    'Guest3' => 0
    );


    if (isset($_POST['fname'],$_POST['lname'],
                $_POST['email'],$_POST['tel'],
                $_POST['comment'],$_POST['guestnum'],
                $_POST['guest3'],$_POST['guest2'],
                $_POST['guest3'])) 
    {
        $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
        $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        $tel =   test_input($_POST["tel"]);
        $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
        $guestnum = test_input($_POST["guestnum"]);
        $guest1 = test_input($_POST["guest1"]);
        $guest2 = test_input($_POST["guest2"]);
        $guest3 = test_input($_POST["guest3"]);

        $json['success'] = true;
        $json['FirstName'] = $fname;
        $json['LastName'] = $lname;
        $json['Email'] = $email;
        $json['Phone'] = $tel;
        $json['Comments'] = $comment;
        $json['GuestNumber'] = $guestnum;
        $json['Guest1'] = $guest1;
        $json['Guest2'] = $guest2;
        $json['Guest3'] = $guest3;

    }
        $file = 'weddingRSVP.json';
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),1);
        $data[] = $json;
        file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));



    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        return $data;
    }
    ?>
```

although most the magic is happening with this code:

```
        $file = 'weddingRSVP.json';
        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),1);
        $data[] = $json;
        file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
```

Thanks to anyone who helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in

```
$data[] = $json;
```

Instead try

```
$data['weddingRSVP'][] = $json
```

Hope it helps

```
    $file = 'weddingRSVP.json';
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file),1);
    $data['weddingRSVP'][] = $json
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($data));
```

Comment: Just trying to help here ☺